# Sentense using is or has

Tags: meaning

What should I use is or has?
How to identify is word is used as adjective or verb?

Tree (is/has) fallen on my car.

My leg (is/has) broken.

People (are/have) killed.

Train (is/has) left.

As I know fallen ,broken, killed, left are adjective and should be followed with is. 
But these words can also be used as verbs.

Please correct me?

Comment: I was so tempted to leave an answer to this.... :) But seriously, all decisions happen with a specific context. *How to identify whether a word is used as an adjective or a verb?* The definite answer would be *Where?!* It's not like you're always gonna face a three-word sentence, but when the speaker makes sure either interpretation would achieve what they wanted you to perceive.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between 'has' and 'is' is the difference between active and passive; 'has' is active, 'is' is passive. However, one of your sentences uses '*is*' as a [linking verb](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/linkingverb.htm). The others **don't**; you are confusing adjectives with the **perfect** tense, which you may not have learnt yet.

For each of your sentences:

- "The tree **has** fallen on my car." It was the tree itself doing the falling, so the verb must be active.
- "My leg **is** broken" uses *is* as a linking verb, so it means that at the time of writing, the leg is broken. "My leg **has** broken" means that some time in the past, your leg broke; it could already be healed.
- "People **are** killed" means that some people were killed by something or someone else; the people are dead now. "People **have** killed" means that some people were doing the killing; they could have been hunting for deer or other wild animals, for example.
- "The train **has** left" means that the train itself moved away some time in the past; this is what you would say if you missed your train. "The train **is** left" means that the train was left (abandoned) by somebody or something else; for example, so you would only use this is someone parked their train on a trainyard for maintenance, for example.

Finally, don't forget that you should put articles in front of nouns, so 'The train has left', not 'Train has left'.

Comment: "The train is left." could also mean "The train is to the left.", where 'left' refers to the location of the train rather than its state.

Comment: I would also note that "My leg has broken." would most likely be used only if your leg had very recently been broken - before even having gone to a hospital. If your leg had been broken in the past but is no longer broken, one would be more likely to say "My leg was broken."